# Enumerate records in table on multiple columns

Tags: sql

```
ID     descr    points  
----------------------
1000    24      100 
1000    24      40  
1000    25      100
1000    25      40  
2000    24      100
2000    25      100
2000    26      100
```

Above is my table. I want to add/update column enumerating records on basis of **ID** and **descr**. How can I do that?

Below is the result I am looking for.

```
ID     descr    points   order# 
-------------------------------
1000    24      100         1 
1000    24      40          2
1000    25      100         1  
1000    25      40          2
2000    24      100         1
2000    25      100         2
2000    26      100         3
```

Comment: What SQL product are you using? What have you tried so far? Did you search Stackoverflow already? I'm pretty sure this has been answered before. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are going by ID and descr, wouldn't the order # for each ID = 2000 be 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANSI standard function `row_number():

```
select id, descr, points,
       row_number() over (partition by id, descr order by points desc) as ordernum
from t;
```